# Apple Mach-0 Linker Error when building iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making an iOS and I just installed CocoaPods with RESTKit. I also have JSON files. The Apple Mach-O Linker Error happens when I build and only started when I installed the CocoaPods with RESTKit.

Here is part of the error report.

```
ld: 586 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I've worked with CocoaPods and RestKit quite a bit. There isn't enough information in your question to be able to answer it. Did you try and include RestKit directly into your project before including it via CocoaPods (if you did, you shouldn't have)? It's also possible the error is due to some other change you unknowingly introduced at the same time.

Comment: I tried adding RESTKit in its raw form to the project but then I deleted it (I removed the reference as well).

Comment: Are there any other libraries you may have included directly, not via CocoaPods? Also, there's more information behind the linker error. Which symbols are duplicated, and where are they reference from? The linker gives that information.

Comment: I added a JSON library.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar symptom occur when I have added a static library that included another library that I already had in the project.  It may be that you already have a library included in your project that is also included int the CocoaPods with RESTKit.